# Filter for MS Graph Delta

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, postman, onedrive, microsoft-graph-delta

How can I filter a request in MS Graph Delta ?

For example I want to filter files (OneDrive) with the extension .xlsx

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/delta?$filter=endsWith(name,'.xlsx')
```

But unfortunately I get as a response all the files that are saved (.docx files etc.)

Comment: If you talk about Microsoft Graph + Onedrive along with delta then it supports only select, expand and top odata query parameters only and not the filter. Here's [the doc talks about the same](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

Comment: But what I find strange is according to IDriveItemDeltaRequest (from Graph SDK) in C# the filter is supported. IDriveItemDeltaRequest Filter(string value)